# Parsing "置かれている" in this sentence?

Tags: parsing

I have a quick question about how one would parse the following:

> だが、別段そこに『キングダム』の要となる物が置かれているというわけではない。

I'm a little confused by what "置かれている" is supposed to mean here and how one would parse it into a sentence.

The best I can come up with is  "However, it's not like the 'kingdom' was something essential to that place." I haven't included "置かれている" in that attempt though, I can't see how this word fits in?

For context this line comes from an introduction in a story, it's describing a mysterious place hidden in the shadows of   『キングダム』where powerful men secretly gather.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is more deeply nested than you think. Treat `『キングダム』の要となる物` as one set which serves as the subject of 置かれている.

> 別段［そこに｛『キングダム』の要となる物｝が置かれている］というわけではない。

- 『キングダム』の要となる物
  a thing that serves as the cornerstone of *The Kingdom*
- そこに『キングダム』の要となる物が置かれている
  a thing that serves as the cornerstone of *The Kingdom* is placed there
- そこに『キングダム』の要となる物が置かれているというわけではない。
  It is not that a thing that serves as the cornerstone of *The Kingdom* is placed there.

別段 is an adverb meaning "(not) particularly".

Answer (score 0):

I was advised to put my answer in here.So, My translation and break things down.

But:だが, 別段ない: not in particular, というわけ: it is the case, 置かれている: is assembled, そこに『キングダム』の要となる物がある: There is something for the foundation of "Kingdom" in there. Now, I put them together. But, it is not the case in particular that there is something which is assembled for the foundation of "Kingdom".